# svn folder show up on svn ls but isn't in my repository

Tags: svn

I have messed up the order of deleting locally, svn delete, and commit (something in there went wrong), and now a folder shows up in my 'svn ls' in my checkout directory, that isn't actually on the repository. If I try to reuse that folder name, svn won't commit any files in the folder. It will give me the following error message:

```
svn: File already exists: filesystem '/repos/svn/****/db', transaction '64-28', path '/portable_robot/ur5_moveit'
```

It would be very helpful to use that name, because it is a specific application in my program. How so I clean up my local svn tree?

Comment: Have you done an `svn up` and/or `svn cleanup` to see if they "fix" the quirk?

Comment: I have done svn cleanup. Is up different?

Comment: Update pulls the latest changes from the repository, ensuring your local copy is up to date. If you have committed a delete elsewhere, this would ensure that the state is right in your local copy.

Comment: Ah update! Yes I've done update, cleanup and tried readding an empty directory of the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you've described, I'd say you have two choices:

First, you could `svn revert` your checkout directory (or parts of it). This would remove *all local changes* in the directory (or directories) you specify. Then you could work through the delete, commit, add, etc. steps to get your directory cleaned up.

Second, you could checkout a new copy in a new directory and make your changes there ensuring that each step works.

Comment: Checking out anew seems to work. I think I could have solved this using tortoise svn's repo browser, but I'm not sure how to do the same from command line.